# url does not change when redirecting using request.getRequestDispatcher("../login.jsp")

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

On session logout the page should redirect to `login.jsp`.

It is redirecting to login.jsp if I use `request.getRequestDispatcher("../login.jsp").forward(request, response)` but the url is not changing.

what should I do so that it go and change the url too and redirect me to login page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
response.sendRedirect("/yourcontextPath/login.jsp);
```

---

**See**

- [difference between forwarding and redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646650/difference-between-forwarding-and-redirection)