# Using Send Redirect to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I Have problem When redirect to jsp . I Have put my servlet code below. and also I have put error log. Can any one please help me to fix the problem. If you need further details pl comment it below. I Have done samething in other servlet It is working .

```
  public class DoctorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String sDocId=request.getParameter("doctorId");
        Integer dId=Integer.parseInt(sDocId);
        String speciality=request.getParameter("speciality");
        String experience=request.getParameter("experience");
        String qualification=request.getParameter("qualification");
        String sempId=request.getParameter("employeeId");
        Integer empId=Integer.parseInt(sempId);
        String action=request.getParameter("method");

        Doctors d=new Doctors();

        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){

            d.setDocId(dId);
            d.setEmpId(empId);
            d.setExp(experience);
            d.setSumOfQn(qualification);
            d.setSpeciality(speciality);
            try {
                boolean result=new Doctors().insertDoctor(d);
                if(result==true){

                    request.setAttribute("add","sucess");
                }
                  request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor_result.jsp").forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("doctor_result.jsp");


            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoctorServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }


    }


}
```

---

```
    Aug 23, 2012 12:29:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DoctorServlet] in context with path [/AsiaHospital] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:483)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
    at com.asiahospital.servlet.DoctorServlet.doPost(DoctorServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: It is better to have a `return;` after `response.sendRedirect("doctor_result.jsp");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forwarding to some other JSP so it commits the response

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor_result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

now you are trying to send the response back which is already committed

```
response.sendRedirect("doctor_result.jsp");
```

which is invalid

You should either forward or redirect the same response instance

---

**See Also**

- [difference between forwarding and redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646650/difference-between-forwarding-and-redirection)

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by a classpath contamination. Make sure that /WEB-INF/lib doesn't contain something like jsp-api-*.jar.

Comment: how does this answer the question ?