# Set an html page as servlet response

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've defined a webservlet as follows:

```
@WebServlet(name = "HomeWebServlet", urlPatterns = "/")
public class HomeWebServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException { 
       // Content
    }

 }
```

How can I set as response an html page (`index.html`) placed in `src/main/webapp/resources` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just `forward` request to jsp page

```
String nextJSP = "/yourJsp.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**You updated question from jsp to html**

in that case you just need to redirect user to goto HTML, since src/main/webapp is in public web space it would be available to user directly

```
response.sendRedirect("/yourHtml.html")
```

or you still can forward request to html

```
String nextHTML = "/yourHtml.html";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextHTML);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I'd like to set the content, not a route redirect.

Comment: @vdenotaris [forward is not the same as redirect!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8646650/1113392)