# using <c:redirect> tag in Spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, redirect

So, I am displaying a jsp. Inside that JSP, there is a  tag, this way:

```
<c:redirect url="step1.jsp"></c:redirect>
```

The origin JSP is inside `myProjName/src/main/webapp//WEB-INF/views`. The JSP I want to redirect to is inside that folder, too. But Tomcat cant find it. What's the proper route I have to set in my  tag?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`include/forward` might help you.

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/step1.jsp" %>
```

OR

```
<jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/views/step1.jsp"/>
```

OR

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/abc.jsp"/>
```

but `forward` and `include` don't change the URL in the browser address bar as well as the response is included in the page from where it is called.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646650/difference-between-forwarding-and-redirection)

Answer (score 0):

What does the URL that you are sitting on look like (the one displayed in your browser that is failing with the error)?

I'm guessing you already tried:

?