# Unable to redirect from Jsp to another in Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I am implementing a login application with JSP (better I could have used thymeleaf), bootstap as frontend and Spring Boot as backend. I have placed the jsp inside `/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/view/`.

Now I have created two jsp, `login.jsp` and `registration.jsp`. Inside `login.jsp` I have given an href link to another jsp as below

```
<a href="registration.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Sign Up</a>
```

When I click on the `Sign Up` button I am getting the `404` error.
After searching for a while I have come to know that it is trying to find the jsps inside `/main/webapp/jsp/`

Now it would be weird if I keep the jsp file inside `/main/webapp/jsp/` having said inside the documentation that the jsp has to be placed in resources folder and i have kept all the jsps inside resources folder.

Comment: You are trying very old development method. If you configured spring boot create controller classes for handling requests from client .

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843031/8112217, but I also agree with @SumeshTG

Comment: @SumeshTG: Thanks Got it