# Doesn't Redirect JavaFaces 2.0 Primefaces p:commandButton o p:commandLink

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, primefaces, faces-config

Im having some problems with redirections. Im using primefaces and JSF 2.1. The thing is that JSF 2.1 doesn't have navigations rules and searching for an answer i found that I can put "faces-redirect=true". The problem is that that doesnt worked and i dont know why. The browser keeps telling me "No se puede encontrar el caso de navegación coincidente del ID de vista '/Autenticacion/login.xhtml' para la acción {1}' con el resultado '{2}'" Something like i dont have a navigation case for "/Autenticacion/login.xhtml" for the first action with the second result. With JSF 2.1 does not create a faces-config.xml file i create it and I added the rule for that action but the problem persists.

These are my files:

LOGIN BEAN

```
@ManagedBean(name="controlLogin")
@SessionScoped
public class ControladorLogin implements Serializable{

   public String logIn(){
       //actions
       return "index" //algo tryed index.xhtml or index?faces-redirect=true
   }
```

PRIMEFACES COMMANDBUTTON

```
<p:commandButton action="#{controlLogin.logIn}" value="Loguearse" ajax="false"/>
```

I also try with a commandLink

```
<p:commandLink action="#{controlLogin.logIn}" value="Loguearse" ajax="false"/>
```

FACES-CONFIG.XML //IF IS NOT NECESARY I CAN DELETE IT

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/Autenticacion/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{controlLogin.logIn}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

So if anyone can help me to do this redirection...thanks!!

Comment: Try using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(yourURL);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, in **JSF 2.x** you don't have to define navigation rules. You don't need `faces-config.xml` at all, just in some special cases which are not covered with **annotations** (eg. custom `ExceptionHandlerFactory`).

Using `return "index?faces-redirect=true"` is completely fine. `faces-redirect=true` means that you `redirect` from one xhtml to another instead of **default** `forward`.

[Difference between forward and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect)

In this case just make sure that your `index.xhtml` page is in the same directory as the page from which you try to access it.

Otherwise if the `index` page is located in **another** directory then you have to specify **absolute path** with forward slash `/` in the beggining like this: `"/indexFolder/index?faces-redirect=true"`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. just for the record, like i'm working with java-faces i had to add the "/faces" to the folder path where is my page. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a guess. You have probably defined `<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>` in your `web.xml`. If you change (or add new) `url-pattern` to `<url-pattern>*.jsf (or *.xhtml)</url-pattern>` it will work without adding the "/faces" to folder path.