# Web. Some nuances of difference between forward and redirect

Tags: http, web-applications, redirect, forward, http-redirect

I'm starting to learn web-programming. I've read about the difference between `forward` and `redirect`. But two questions not fully understood still:

1. In which case does the process access **to a server-side** and in which case **without server-side**?
2. When does **URL** change and when doesn't change? Does URL changes **always when redirecting**? Does URL changes **never when forwarding**?

I would be very grateful for the clear answers and explanations! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't abuse the tags. Your question has nothing to do with C#, PHP or Java. I fixed them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between jsp forward and redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

They are not hard and fast terms.

A redirect *usually* means an HTTP redirect, which is an HTTP response that instructs the client to make a new HTTP request to a different URI.

An *internal redirect* is a common description of a redirect that is handled internally by the webserver / web application / etc and doesn't send the browser to a different URI.

Forward is not a particularly common term, but when I've encountered it it *usually* means a form of internal redirect.

Answer (score 0):

`Forward` happens on serverside, server forwards the same request to another resource. whereas `redirect` happens on the browser side, server sends http status code 302 to browser so browser makes new request.

Redirect requires one more round trip from browser to server.

One more difference is redirect reflects in browser address bar forward doesnt.