# How to transmit parameter to redirected jsp that this parameter is accesable into this jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/path", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String path(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)  {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("attr", "valueFromPath");
        return "redirect:jspPage.jsp";//this page located in webApp folder
    }
```

jspPage.jsp:

```
...
<h1>${attr}</h1>
...
```

In my case this row is empty, but I want that `valueFromPath` will shown on this jsp.

How I can make it?

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is your `DispatcherServlet` responsible for handling the request to `jspPage.jsp`? Or is it loaded by the default `Servlet`?

Comment: I use DispatcherServlet

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Show us how your `DispatcherServlet` handles the new request to `jspPage.jsp`. Post your web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make an assumption here. Because of your URL mapping of

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

The `DispatcherServlet` is not handling the request for `jspPage.jsp`. That jobs falls on the [default `Servlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/funcspecs/fs-default.html). As such, the `DispatcherServlet` cannot perform the logic that adds the flash attributes from the `HttpSession` attributes back into the request attributes.

You need to make sure that the request for `jspPage.jsp` is handled by the `DispatcherServlet`. Either by moving the file to some other location or changing your `url-pattern` to `/` and providing a handler.

Comment: @homeAccount I don't know if you say, but I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, I am rewrite mapping for / .Now I see my variable value in browser adress field but this value is not available on page as ${attr}

Comment: I don't want write handler. If I replace redirect by the forward - it is works how I want.

Comment: and use model.addAttribute instead redirectAttributes

Comment: @homeAccount [A `redirect` and a `forward` are two completely different things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect) and prove I was right. When using a `forward`, the model attributes will be added to the request attributes first, then the request will be dispatched with a forward which will immediately render the `jsp` by the `DefaultServlet`. With a `redirect`, the flash attributes are only added to the request attributes after the request, but the `DispatcherServlet` doesn't handle the next request so they aren't available.