# How to block the JSP being called by GET method

Tags: jsp, methods, get, block, invocation

I have an existing JSP which is coded like this.

```
<% 
  if( (request.getParameter("userid")!=null) && (request.getParameter("token")!=null) ) {

     session.setParameter("USERID", request.getParameter(userid);
     session.setParameter("Token", request.getParameter(token);

     send.redirect(another.jsp);
  }
%>

< ----- here i have the normal HTML contents where i ask for userid from the user 
        and upon clicking submit, java script function openwindow() is called ----- >

function openwindow(){

   < -- here i open a modal window which calls a URL with userid (get method) 
        and as return value i get userid and token back. 
        Now i set this to document.Parent.userid and document.Parent.token --- >

    document.Parent.userid = retval.userid;
    document.Parent.token = retval.token;
    Parent.submit();
}
```

With the above mentioned JSP, I face a problem that when I invoke the JSP using `sample.jsp?userid=dhfgd&token=dhdhd`, the control directly goes to `another.jsp` since the request parameters are set.

To avoid this, kindly suggest me a probable solution without making much changes in code.

Comment: You are redirecting to `another.jsp` if `userid` and `token` is not `null` then where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use *include* instead of *redirect* to `another.jsp` if you want to include the content generated by `another.jsp` as well in the response of the actual `sample.jsp` page.

Read more about the [difference between jsp forward and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect)

---

You can retrieve the request method using [HttpServletRequest#getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) and then simply send an error page if GET request is not supported in JSP.

Comment: Thanks.. I resolved it by checking whether the same is GET or POST as u had suggested. :)

Comment: Good news. Don't forget to close the thread if the issue is resolved.