# Servlet sendRedirect doesn't work correctly

Tags: jsp, redirect, servlets

Trying to perform a redirection from the doPost of Servlet A, to Servlet B.
I performed the following code:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/App/BServlet");
return;
```

And i can see the navigator having 302 HTTP code performing the GET request to the right location, but the doGet method of Servlet B isn't executed.

Tried with a 301 Http manner, using this code:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location","http://localhost:8080/App/BServlet");
```

And in this case, the BServlet doGet method is executed but, a forward to a jsp page which is included in the doGet method of Servlet B isn't forwarding to the jsp page, the navigator stays at the same page.

Any clue ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't change from a get to a post. If you start with a post you must use a post in servlet b also

Comment: @Jonathan Doesn't redirection, starts a new http query ? (GET again) ? source: https://javabeat.net/difference-forward-sendredirect-servlet/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect

Comment: Yes. But if you start with a post then redirect to another servlet, then the post will be called, always.

Comment: @Jonathan, clear answer (y), thanks for it (y)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned it Jonathan, and may some others check the answer, i was starting by a POST request, due to this, all the following requests will be post ones also even if a redirect start a new request.