# Redirct to specific URL?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a question about redirection from specific URL inside pagination to other URL without affecting other pages.

Let's say I want to redirect this URL: `https://www.fwdindex.com/directory-list.php?p=1&sb=name&so=asc` to `https://www.fwdindex.com/directory-list.php`
without affecting `https://www.fwdindex.com/directory-list.php?p=2&sb=name&so=asc`
etc.

Is it possible to do this with httaccess?

Comment: Try 301 redirect...

Comment: i.e. Redirect 301 Old URL <space> New URL

Comment: You need http forward and not http redirect
This link can be of your help https://stackoverflow.com/a/6068925/1489638