# Is there a way to call a function in a .jsp from the back?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, url, redirect

I captured an URL:(example)

> https://lol.com/question2

In a variable in my .jsp, then I have to log in and in the back, after validating that the login was correct, I'm redirecting the page to the home of my application but what I want is to redirect it the URL that I captured before login in. Is there a way to capture that variable in the back when its about to redirect? Like calling a function in front from the back so that it returns the URL?

This is the function from where I redirect:

```
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    var urlNew = functionToCaptureURL();

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(urlNew);
    //redirectStrategy.sendRedirect("https://lol.com/home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RequestDispatcher::forward](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-) instead of `sendRedirect`. Check [Difference between JSP forward and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please before send login request fill referer header by your captured url, then create a class which extends the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class and call `setUseReferer(true)` on overriden method `RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler()`.
for more info check this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login